# Protect table from wrong data using locks or transactions

Tags: mysql, transaction

I have two tables

flats

```
   id - primary key
   title - text
```

flats_reservations

```
   id - primary key
   flat_id - foreign key to flats(id)
   creator_id - foreign key to users(id)
   is_reserved - boolean
   created_at - current_timestamp
```

If flats_reservations has these rows

```
id=1, flat_id=12, creator_id=5, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:00
id=2, flat_id=12, creator_id=5, is_reserved=0, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:05
id=3, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:10
```

Then **only** user with id=4 can remove reservation (e.g. insert following row (**is_reserved=0**)

```
id=4, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=0, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:10
```

No other user can make this. At any point of time only one user can `reserve` flat.

Can I use mysql transactions to ensure that two users at the same time can not `reserve` flat?

I want to be sure, that following rows can not be inserted at once

```
id=5, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:15
id=6, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:15
```

In application I use following queries in transactions

```
# transaction start
select is_reserved from flat_reservations where flat_id=12 order by created_at desc limit 1;
# if is_reserved == 0 or query returned 0 rows then
insert into `flat_reservations` (`flat_id`, `creator_id`, `is_reserved`) values (12, 4, 1)
# commit
```

Is there some way to lock table during execution of these two queries and *only* when flat_id=12?

Users must be able to `reserve` other flats (e.g., where id is not 12).

If it is not possible then should I lock whole table for writing?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Add `FOR UPDATE` to the `SELECT`.

Plan B:  Add `UNIQUE(flat_id, creator_id, is_reserved)`

If neither of those work, then I am confused by your business logic; please explain further.